# operator override like .net in php classes

Tags: php

I have one class with multiple numeric values and functionality 
(for some kind of count category etc.)

```
class mBasicClass
{
    public $typ01Value = 0;
    public $typ02Value = 0;
}
```

I also have some other classes which are actually group of these classes

```
class mClass
{
    public $vjA = new mBasicClass();
    public $ntB = new mBasicClass();
    public $ntC = new mBasicClass();
    public $ntD = new mBasicClass();
}
```

All I want to know - is there any way to write operator override like .net in php classes

so that I can use

```
$vjA + $ntB
```

Which actually is

```
$vjA->$typ01Value + $ntB ->$typ01Value
$vjA->$typ02Value + $ntB ->$typ02Value
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The request for PHP object operator overloading has been an open ticket since 2001:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=9331

So unfortunately you cannot do what you are asking :(

Instead you'll have to create a function like `addObjects($obj1, $obj2)` and do the manual calculations yourself:

```
addObjects($obj1, $obj2)
{
    $new_obj = new mBasicClass();
    $new_obj->typ01Value = $obj1->typ01Value + $obj2->typ01Value;
    $new_obj->typ02Value = $obj1->typ02Value + $obj2->typ02Value;

    return $new_obj;
}
```

then use it:

```
$result = addOjbects($vjA, $ntB);
```

Comment: Thanks Sven, Hope PHP will offer this to us soon.